# Simplifying if clause and record retrieval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code structure like this:

```
if params[:one] && params[:two]
  object = Something.where(:one => params[:one], :two => params[:two])
elsif params[:one]
  object = Something.where(:one => params[:one])
elsif params[:two]
  object = Something.where(:two => params[:two])
else
  object = Something.all
end
```

Basically, two optional parameters in the URL that filter the query to be made. Can this be cleaner?

Comment: This should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write:

```
objects = Something.where(params.slice(:one, :two))
```

Notes:

1. Usually an empty param is also to be considered as non-existing. In this case: `Something.where(params.slice(:one, :two).select { |k, v| v.present? })`.
2. Strange as it may look, in your snippet you should write `object = if ...`, it's far more idiomatic being Ruby a language where conditionals are expressions and not statements.
3. Don't call `all` as a no-op, you don't have a `ActiveRecord::Relation` (cool) anymore, but a `Array` (not so cool). `where({})` is perfectly fine.
4. Naming is very important! If you see `object` you think "single element" (which is not true here), if you see `objects` you think "collection".
5. If the param keys does not match DB columns: a lot of ways to do it, for example:

   ```
   pairs = {:x => :db_x, :y => db_y}.map { |k, v| [v, params[k]] if params[k] }]
   Something.where(Hash[pairs.compact])
   ```

Or being just two attributes:

```
attrs = {:db_one => params[:one], :db_two => params[:two]}
Something.where(attrs.select { |k, v| v })
```

Comment: Will this work if params doesn't have any of those keys?  That is, passing an empty hash to `.where`...

Comment: Yes, `where({})` does no filtering.

Comment: @tokland Thanks for the response. What would be the syntax if the param keys don't correspond directly to the database columns?

Comment: @tokland Even though the question has been closed, this did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing something like so (chaining criteria):

```
object = Something.all
object = object.where(:one => params[:one]) if params[:one]
object = object.where(:two => params[:two]) if params[:two]
```